# Concatenating over a date range and limit to a single field

Tags: ms-access, concatenation

When I set up Allen Browne's ConcatRelated in a query to use a date range, I get ever comment in that range in each comment field.  I want to group by an assembly line name but I get each line's comments.  My SQL query is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried a sub query but I still get the same result or a syntax error depending on how I format.

```
SELECT 
Asm_Equipment_Rate.Line_Name,
Avg(Asm_Equipment_Rate.Std_Pnls_Lbr_Hr) AS RAsm_Line_Std_Hrs,
Sum(Asm_Prod_Data.Lbr_Hrs) AS RAsm_Line_Total_Hrs,
([RAsm_Line_Std_Hrs]*[RAsm_Line_Total_Hrs]) AS RT100_Pct_Target, 
([RT100_Pct_Target]*0.9) AS RT90_Pct_Target, 
Sum(Asm_Prod_Data.Produced) AS RTotal_Produced, 
Sum(Asm_Prod_Data.Backflushed) AS RTotal_Backflushed, 
[RTotal_Produced]/[RT100_Pct_Target] AS RAsm_Line_EFF,
Sum(Asm_Prod_Data.Scrap_Qty) AS RAsm_Scrapped_Panels, 
Sum(Asm_Prod_Data.Reworked) AS RAsm_Reworked_Panels, 
IIf(([RAsm_Scrapped_Panels]+[RAsm_Reworked_Panels])=0,1,1-
([RAsm_Scrapped_Panels]+[RAsm_Reworked_Panels])/([RAsm_Scrapped_Panels]+
[RAsm_Reworked_Panels]+[RTotal_Produced])) AS RFYP,
ConcatRelated
        ('Comments',
         'Asm_Prod_Data',
         'PA_date Between ' & Format([Forms]![Date Prompt]!
[txtBDate],'\#yyyy-m-d\#') & ' And ' & Format([Forms]![Date Prompt]!
[txtEDate],'\#yyyy-m-d\#'),
'Comments',
     ', ') AS RConCat_Comments
FROM Asm_Equipment_Rate INNER JOIN Asm_Prod_Data ON    

Asm_Equipment_Rate.Equipment = Asm_Prod_Data.P_Line

WHERE (((Asm_Prod_Data.PA_Date) Between [Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtBDate] 
And [Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtEDate]))
GROUP BY Asm_Equipment_Rate.Line_Name;
```

Regards,

Bill

Answer (score 0):

change the WHERE clause to

```
'PA_date Between ' & 
  Format([Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtBDate],'\#yyyy-m-d\#') & 
' And ' & Format([Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtEDate],'\#yyyy-m-d\#') & 
' And P_Line=' & Asm_Prod_Data.P_Line,
```

You'll need to quote the value if P_Line is text.

Also, I think when you call a function you need to use double quotes inside the function call, although if what you have there is working, that's not true. Maybe it's changed for later Access versions.

EDIT: I mean the WHERE clause in the function call

Try this

```
SELECT 
Asm_Equipment_Rate.Line_Name,
ConcatRelated
        ('Comments',
         'Asm_Prod_Data',
         'PA_date Between ' 
             & Format([Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtBDate],'\#yyyy-m-d\#') 
             & ' And ' & Format([Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtEDate],'\#yyyy-m-d\#')
             & ' And P_Line=' & Asm_Prod_Data.P_Line,
         'Comments',
         ', ') AS RConCat_Comments
FROM Asm_Equipment_Rate INNER JOIN Asm_Prod_Data 
   ON Asm_Equipment_Rate.Equipment = Asm_Prod_Data.P_Line

WHERE (((Asm_Prod_Data.PA_Date) Between [Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtBDate] 
And [Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtEDate]))

GROUP BY Asm_Equipment_Rate.Line_Name,
    ConcatRelated
        ('Comments',
         'Asm_Prod_Data',
         'PA_date Between ' 
             & Format([Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtBDate],'\#yyyy-m-d\#') 
             & ' And ' & Format([Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtEDate],'\#yyyy-m-d\#')
             & ' And P_Line=' & Asm_Prod_Data.P_Line,
         'Comments',
         ', ');
```

It's unfortunate but the GROUP BY expression has to be identical to the one in the SELECT clause, no matter how complex.

Comment: I tried the suggestion and I got back this error message.  "You tried to execure a query that does not include the specificed expression ConcatRelated ('Comments', 'Asm_Prod_Data', 'PA_date Between ' & Format([Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtBDate],'\#yyyy-m-d\#') & ' And ' & Format([Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtEDate],'\#yyyy-m-d\#') & ' And P_Line=' & Asm_Prod_DAta.P_Line,'Comments', ', ') AS RConCat_Comments', ', ') as part of an aggreate function."

Comment: I'd expect that, because you're using Group By. You need to repeat the expression in the Group By clause. But I don't get why you weren't getting that error before. I'd strongly suggest simplifying the query to the basics, losing the aggregation and the joined table, then upscaling it again once the basic one is working.

Comment: Well i am finally getting time to work on this again.  I have simpflied the query but I am still having the same problem of it not spliting out the comments by line name.  It groups them all together or I get an error.

Comment: Here is the query.SELECT Asm_Prod_Data.P_Line_Name, 
ConcatRelated
('Comments',
'Asm_Prod_Data',
'PA_date Between ' 
& Format([Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtBDate],'\#yyyy-m-d\#') 
& ' And ' 
& Format([Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtEDate],'\#yyyy-m-d\#') 
& ' And   P_Line_Name=' & 'Asm_Prod_Data.P_Line_Name', 
 'Comments',', ') AS RConCat_Comments
FROM Asm_Prod_Data
WHERE 'PA_date Between ' & 
  Format([Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtBDate],'\#yyyy-m-d\#') & 
' And ' & Format([Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtEDate],'\#yyyy-m-d\#') & 
' And P_Line=' & Asm_Prod_Data.P_Line_Name
GROUP BY P_Line_Name;